Article on 1D deformed quantum harmonic oscillator
Few years ago I was reading an article which I'm trying to find for quite some time but with no success so far. It was a paper about deformation of 1D quantum harmonic oscillator with continuous deformation parameter affecting only the potential energy and in the limit of deformation parameter approaching infinity the system reduced to the standard harmonic oscillator. Ladder operators formalism was developed for that problem in the paper and the error function $\textrm{erf}(x)$ occured in eigenfunctions. I also remember that wave function of ground state had a little more complicated form then for excited states, it was expressed by the integral of some function involving error function $\textrm{erf}(x)$. It was not a recent article, it was from 80s if I remember correctly. If anybody recognize this paper I would be very thankful for help.

The problem has been beaten to a pulp, cf this review. You might be recalling this one, Brodimas, Jannussis et al, 1981.

@CosmasZachos thank you for your answer. I finally found the article I was looking for. It was this paper written by B. Mielnik.
